# ListBox Items are from Strings Declared in Other Class Possible?

Tags: c#, icsharpcode

related to this topic:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15170054/context-hint-using-combobox

Is there a way I can use the strings in my separate class:

```
namespace KeyWord
{
    public class KeyWord
    {
        //Definitions
    public String[] keywords = { "abstract", "as", "etc." };
    }
}
```

to mylistbox items in my mainform?

```
lb = new ListBox();
        Controls.Add(lb);
```

ty in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure.  Try something like this.

```
KeyWord kw = new KeyWord();
foreach (string str in kw.keywords)
{
    lb.Items.Add(str);
}
```

Or you can use databinding.

Also, if all you're doing is getting an array of strings from that class, you might want to use a static property so you don't have to instantiate an instance of that object.  I would recommend using properties either way for exposing public data, instead of a public field.

Here's an example of using a static property, instead:

```
public class KeyWord
{
    // Private field, only accessible within this class
    private static string[] _keywords = { "abstract", "as", "etc." };

    // Public Static Property, accessible wherever
    public static string[] Keywords
    {
        get { return _keywords; }
        set { _keywords = value; }
    }
}
```

Then:

```
foreach (string str in KeyWord.Keywords)
{
    lb.Items.Add(str);
}
```

Notice, I didn't instantiate the class in this example (no `new KeyWords()`)

Comment: A new expression requires (), [], or {} after type , pointing the KeyWord;

Comment: I fixed it about 10 seconds after I posted it :P ... `new KeyWord();` (forgot the parentheses at first)

Comment: nice you got it right sir really thanks for that, but what if i need to apply 2individual group of strings in just a listbox? is that possible also sir? like:  public String[] keywords and public String[] events from class

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean.  You just want to add two arrays to the list?  You can continue to append values to the listBox by calling `lb.Items.Add("something else");`

Comment: answered by myself: KeyWord keywordsL = new KeyWord();
        KeyWord eventsL = new KeyWord();
        foreach (string str in keywordsL.keywords)
        {
         lb.Items.Add(str);
        }
        foreach (string str in eventsL.events)
        {
            lb.Items.Add(str);
        } gee really thanks for the help :D